# SDL: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, g++, sdl, x86-64

I'm working on a simple wrapper for SDL to function as a sort of game engine. At the moment I have a simple temporary main function that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Still in development!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Along with some simple functions for the wrapper:

```
#include "SDL.h"

namespace snowshoe
{
  void initialize()
  {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  }

  void release()
  {
    SDL_Quit();
  }

  void update(SDL_Surface * screen)
  {
    SDL_Flip(screen);
  }
}
```

But when I try to compile the two I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Flip", referenced from:
      snowshoe::update(SDL_Surface*)      in snowshoe-iru.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      snowshoe::initialize()              in snowshoe-iru.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      snowshoe::release()                 in snowshoe-iru.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Before anyone asks, I've included all the flags I need:

```
`sdl-config --cflags` -lSDL
```

Any ideas? I'm running OSX Mountain Lion and compiling from the command line (not Xcode).

Comment: Can you show us the output of sdl-config --cflags ?

Comment: @selalerer It's `-I/usr/local/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE`

Comment: What's the output of `sdl-config --libs`?

Comment: @Xymostech `-L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -Wl,-framework,Cocoa`

Comment: What happens if you replace `-lSDL` with `\`sdl-config --cflags\``?

Comment: @Xymostech same error but shorter output (there was some stuff regarding `-lSDL` before the error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `sdl-config --cflags --libs`

on my system it gives

-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL

for example, I do

g++ fractal.cpp -O3 -fopenmp -mavx `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -o fractal_gcc_avx